# How to handle select query to return numeric value?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have the following select Query :

```
Dim count As Integer
Select count(*) as mycount from some_table into temp_table
Fetch First From temp_table
count = some_table.mycount
```

But it sends error:

> Expression does not evaluate to string

Now when I saved **temp_table** to ***.tab** file it has **char** column.How to make **some_table.mycount** a number?

But when the Query is

```
Select count(*) from some_table into temp_table
```

It would work but column name is random.

Comment: if there is character column and we just need to find only numric value then what will be the mapinfo sql query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in stead:

```
Dim count As Integer
Select count(*) "mycount" from some_table into temp_table
Fetch First From temp_table
count = temp_table.mycount
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply How do I know what kind of query are supported in Mapinfo

Comment: What queries? Are you looking for some desciption on the syntax? If yes, I would recommend that you have a look in the MapBasic reference guide and in the MapInfo Help system.

Comment: @Peter,is it possible to call an alias for the table,like 

select ... from some_table "Some" ??

Comment: No sure why you would want to do that? I know that is possible in most database systems, but MapInfo Pro doesn't support that. What you could do, is opening your table with an alias (if you do it thru MapBasic that is - the Open dialog doesn't support that)